# Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon Desktop scaling feature missing

Tags: linux-mint, desktop

Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon Desktop scaling feature missing.

---

I need to set Desktop scaling, but this feature is missing in my menu. Is anything missing in the system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get to the Desktop Scaling by opening System Settings>General in the Preferences section.

There is also a post on the Mint User Forums that could also prove to be useful in helping scale your display to your liking which can be found [HERE](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=250690).

---

You can select Double (Hi-DPI) in General preferences as shown below:

[image: Double (Hi-DPI) in General preferences]

Comment: Is there any more flexibility than either x1 or x2? For example can you manually set the UI scaling factor to x1.5?

Comment: Cinnamon is based on gtk3 which only supports integer scaling.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463852/linux-mint-cinnamon-fractional-scaling-1-5x-for-wqhd-displays-missing-any-solu