# Linux Mint Cinnamon fractional scaling 1.5x for WQHD displays missing - any solutions?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, graphics, resolution

Is there any adequate option to scale Linux Mint to a WQHD screen (2.560 x 1.440) with high density?

If I am going to

> System Settings -> General

indeed I have an option for scaling my desktop to fit my screen:

[image: Linux Mint Desktop Scaling Dropdown]

Possible options:

- Auto
- Normal
- Double (High-DPI)

Should do it for Full HD and 4K Screens, but on WQHD it sucks. Either everything is way to large or everything is way to small.

Sure, I can adjust the font and the panel sizes (which is what I did for now), but this still does not solve dozens of problems where everything is either way to big  or way to small.

How could I achieve appropriate scaling?

Comment: +1 would be also interested in a solution

Answer (score 2):

a small workaround could be:

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/interface/scaling-factor 'uint32 2'
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/scaling-factor 'uint32 2'
dconf write /org/cinnamon/active-display-scale 1.5
```

Comment: ty I will try and tell if it works for me

Comment: This isn't ideal - the interface scaling factor is still limited to whole numbers (hence uint32) and the active display scale seems to only alter the bottom toolbar.

Comment: totally agree, but didn't find any better solution. @AriCooper-Davis do you have one?

Comment: @toschneck I did actually, I have added it as an answer :-)

Comment: more details in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly better, still hacky, workaround.

Set your display resolution higher than maximum then use the Double UI scaling to scale it back up to a sensible size. This is pretty much bug free, except possibly for the mouse pointer and for using external displays, both of which are fixable within settings.

---

First, determine which display device you want to change the resolution for (in this case it's `eDP-1`):

```
$ xrandr
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
> eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> ...
```

Then determine the required VESA CVT for your desired resolution, remembering to choose a resolution of the same aspect ratio to your current display (e.g. if your display is currently 1920x1080 then you could try 3200x1800):

```
$ cvt 3200 1800
> # 3200x1800 59.96 Hz (CVT 5.76M9) hsync: 111.82 kHz; pclk: 492.00 MHz
> Modeline "3200x1800_60.00"  492.00  3200 3456 3800 4400  1800 1803 1808 1865 -hsync +vsync
```

Ignore the first comment line, but copy the modeline. Next create a corresponding display mode:

```
$ sudo xrandr --newmode "3200x1800_60.00"  492.00  3200 3456 3800 4400  1800 1803 1808 1865 -hsync +vsync
```

And add that new mode to your display. The display (i.e. `eDP-1`) should be the one that you identified in the first step and the mode should be the newly created one (i.e. `"3200x1800_60.00"`):

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "3200x1800_60.00"
```

Finally select that new resolution in the Display Settings and enable Double UI scaling, for a reasonably sensible experience!

---

**Note:** If you want this change to be preserved on reboot you need to run the last two commands (`--newmode` and `--addmode`) when you login by adding them, without the `sudo`s, to your user profile:

```
$ sudo nano ~/.profile
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For me this does not work due to `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)` when doing `sudo xrandr --addmode DP-0 "3840x2160_60.00"` . Using the commercial nvdia driver 430 (newest). Any suggestions for that?

Comment: I've not come across that, but there are lots of suggestions [on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235507/xconfig-xrandr-badmatch).

Comment: Good point, I tried them all though and it did not work. The reason are probably restrictions by the commercial NVidia driver. I guess your solution is good if used with open source drivers, still I really hope there is some less hacky solution.

Answer (score 2):

I use a script at login for my 4k screen. The result is far from being perfect but will do most of the time. Use xrandr to determine the display port connected as mentioned above:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4800 x 2700, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 4800x2700+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm panning 4800x2700+0+0
```

Create a script (I put it in ~/bin)

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --output DP-2 --fb 4800x2700 --panning 4800x2700 --mode 3840x2160 
xrandr --output DP-2 --scale 1.25x1.25
```

an add it to startup programs. Set your scaling to hidpi in the cinnamon settings (scaling 2.0). To give a hint where the factor came from: 4800 is 1.25*3840 and 2700 is 1.25*2160. With doubeling the GUI output for 4800 and shrinking the result into 3840 via X we have 2/1.25 = 1.6 eq. 160% scaling.

I also made a starter on the desktop with the command line:

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --fb 4800x2700 --panning 4800x2700 --mode 3840x2160
```

to reset screen settings or alternatively disable the cinnamon settings daemon in startup programs because it resets the screen settings to something unuseable when relogin after screen saver.

M. Baehr

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try asap.

Answer (score 0):

System Settings -> Fonts -> Text Scaling Factor

Comment: This makes things better but does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do two things, scaling in firefox, and font scaling, and wrote some scripts to automate this, and ease swapping scales when I plug an alternative monitor into my laptop.

first you must create a file `user.js` in your firefox user profile directory which contains the following:

```
user_pref("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx","1.0");
```

on my machine the profile directory is

```
/home/rcrozier/.mozilla/firefox/7g0khpzd.default-release
```

it is randomly named, so will be different on your machine. Then I use the following to scale firefox:

```
#!/bin/bash

# the following script was taken from here:
#
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/313483/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-aboutconfig-from-a-shell-script
#

profile_dir=${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox/3dqw45da.default-release

sed -i 's/user_pref("'$1'",.*);/user_pref("'$1'",'$2');/' ${profile_dir}/user.js
grep -q $1 ${profile_dir}/user.js || echo "user_pref(\"$1\",$2);" >> ${profile_dir}/user.js
```

I name the above script `ff_set` and use it in my overall scaling script shown below

setdisplayscale

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1 > ${HOME}/.config/current_display_scale_factor

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor $1

ff_set layout.css.devPixelsPerPx "\"$1\""
```

I then also have two little helper scripts to easily set a nice scale for my laptop screen, and turn off scaling when required:

set scale factor to 1.3

```
#!/bin/sh

setdisplayscale 1.3
```

turn off scaling

```
#!/bin/sh

setdisplayscale 1.0
```